# how to use seed-Fu gem in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, seed

I'm trying to work with "seed-fu" gem.I follow the document [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/seed-fu/2.2.0/frames). From that I didn't find the fixtures folder in Rails-ROOT/db/.My db folder contain developement.sqlite3, seeds,rb file.
For that I manually created fixtures under db/fixtures/users.rb.
When giving the command as "rake db:seed_fu". It shows the following in my prompt as,

```
== Seed from D:RAILS_ROOT/db/fixtures/users.rb
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant SeedFu::Runner::User

Tasks: TOP => db:seed_fu
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Whats going on here..?Why I am getting this?
When running "rake db:seed_fu --trace" IT shows the following..,

```
** Invoke db:seed_fu (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:seed_fu

== Seed from /home/ec2-user/malar/app/db/fixtures/user.rb
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant SeedFu::Runner::User
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@a-ms/gems/seed-fu-2.2.0/lib/seed-fu/run
ner.rb:46:in `eval'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@a-ms/gems/seed-fu-2.2.0/lib/seed-fu/run
ner.rb:46:in `eval'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@a-ms/gems/seed-fu-2.2.0/lib/seed-fu/run
ner.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in run_file'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@a-ms/gems/seed-fu-2.2.0/lib/seed-fu/run
ner.rb:58:in `block in open'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@a-ms/gems/seed-fu-2.2.0/lib/seed-fu/run
ner.rb:57:in `open'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@a-ms/gems/seed-fu-2.2.0/lib/seed-fu/run
ner.rb:57:in `open'
```

Comment: with rails version you use ? Have you add this gem in your Gemfile ? Can you launch the same rake command with --trace and past it here the result ?

Comment: Have you a User class existing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the models and the name of the seed data match.  The seed file can be named whatever you like, but the seed data needs to be the same.  See [this blog post](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/04/10/rails-preset-data-in-database-by-seed-fu/) for an example of using Seed Fu.

Answer (score 0):

From the presented details, I can't find out what's wrong with your setup but here's a screencast showing the right way to use it:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data